# Cartesian precisions from spherical standard deviations

Tags: covariance, accuracy, measurement-error, sensor-data

I have to simulate a simple sensor, which has 3 standard deviations defined in spherical frame : sigma-azimuth, sigma-elevation, sigma-distance.
When I simulate a detection, I compute a noisy position using these standard deviations.

Then I have to compute the position and the accuracy in a cartesian frame centered on the sensor. I can do it for the position, but I can't find a formula for the accuracy.

How to compute standard deviation in a cartesian frame from a standard deviation in spherical frame?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is as simple as standard deviation necessarily. Distance, for example is a non-negative quantity, you cannot express uncertainty in distance with some +- because that could violate the sign convention. Instead of coming up with appropriate distributions for spherical coords, it might be better to work backward, from Cartesian

Let your uncertainty in Cartesian be caracterized by multivariate normal

$$
\left(x,y,z\right)\sim Normal\left(\boldsymbol{\mu},\,\boldsymbol{\Sigma}\right)
$$

Now convert this to spherical coordinates

$$
\begin{align}
r&=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\\
\cos\theta&=z/\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\\
\tan\phi&=y/x
\end{align}
$$

The reverse transformation is:

$$
\begin{align}
x&=r\sin\theta\cos\phi \\
y&=r\sin\theta\sin\phi \\
z&=r\cos\theta \\
\end{align}
$$

If probability density for Cartesian coordinates is:

$$
f\left(x,y,z\right)dxdydz=\left(2\pi\right)^{-3/2}\cdot\left|\boldsymbol\Sigma\right|^{-1/2}\cdot\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\left(\begin{array}\\x-\mu_x\\y-\mu_y\\z-\mu_z\end{array}\right)^T.\boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1}.\left(\begin{array}\\x-\mu_x\\y-\mu_y\\z-\mu_z\end{array}\right)^T\right)dxdydz
$$

Then the probability density for the spherical coordinates would be:

$$
\begin{align}
g\left(r,\theta,\phi\right)drd\theta d\phi=f\left(r\sin\theta\cos\phi,\,r\sin\theta\cos\phi,\,r\cos\theta\right)\cdot r^2\sin\theta\cdot dr\,d\theta\,d\phi
\end{align}
$$

Using [spherical volume element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_element)

You can now seek, for example, variance in radial component:

$$
Var\left[r\right]=\int_0^\infty dr \int_0^{2\pi}d\phi\int_0^{\pi}d\theta g\left(r,\,\theta,\,\phi\dots\right)\,r^2
$$

And see how certain values of $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}$ impact what you can observe. For your 'sigma' on polar coordinates, I presume you have 2 values for each coordinate (two ends of the confidence interval) so that's 6 pieces of information, which is precisely the number of degrees of freedom in 3x3 covariance matrix $\boldsymbol{\left(\Sigma\right)}$